# magento fake customer registrations

Tags: magento

i have Fontis reCAPTCHA installed and it has been double checked by another developer to be working. but i keep getting fake customer registrations - about 2 or 3 a day.

they are like this:

```
452     sesBesIdete sesBesIdeteVQ v.e.ronikalikes@gmail.com
451     Monicarj MonicazcGF     Gutermuth@daolemi.com
450     Reennadix ReennadixZB   aldenrivas24@yahoo.co.uk
449     Ommett24 Hmmett67OM     Demoura@daolemi.com
```

any way to stop this?

Comment: no one on this planet has fake mage reg or solution??

Comment: Hey Jon, did you get to the bottom of this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FWIW, upgrading to next version fixed this issue ...now at 1.6.2

Answer (score 0):

This may sound obvious, but what happens when you try to submit a fake account?  I realize that you have the reCaptcha on the site, but how was it implemented?  Does it protect the site if someone submits a form externally?

If you had someone apply reCaptcha without using an actual Magento extension then you may want to consider this one:

http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/Fontis/extension/1169/fontis-recaptcha

Comment: my post states "i have Fontis reCAPTCHA installed"